# Самая эффективная мера борьбы со спамом: тревога -> спам

Tags: обсуждение

Увы, на сайте порядочно спама в последнее время... но для борьбы с ним есть действенная мера: тревога -> спам.

[image: primer]

Как это работает:

- после **трёх** таких тревог вопрос убирается с основной страницы сайта
- после **шести** он удаляется вообще, и притом блокируется IP-адрес, с которого такой спам идёт.

---

Если же просто голосовать за закрытие, например "Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это спам.", то это не столь эффективно, потому что

- спам продолжает висеть на сайте, пусть и закрытым
- блокировка по IP-адресу не применяется

Comment: Thanks, for posting this. I'd loved to be able to do this on my own.
Спасибо, за размещение этого. Я любил быть в состоянии сделать это сам.

Comment: Sally, а если не секрет, а откуда возьмутся  4-я -- 6-я тревоги, если вопрос убран с сайта? И что делать, если основной доступ идет через очередь проверок?! А там "тревоги" нет. Только "закрыть потому, что..."

Comment: Я новые вопросы смотрю только из "проверки", уследить за всем стало невозможно (нет сортировки по дате обновления, комментария и проч. и т.п. - а хотелось бы). А из очнереди проверок - это лишний геморрой, . сколько там раз мышкой надо поработать...

Answer (score 4):

Гладко было на бумаге.
99% посетителей РЯ не занимается проверкой по причине низкого рейтинга и лени.
из оставшихся десяти человек девять не знают, как сделать её эффективной потому, что для этого надо нажать малозаметную кнопочку, а потом еще что-то там выбирать из меню - и т.д. Короче, интерфейс оставляет желать. 
Идеально бы прямо в поле ответа вывесить красную кнопку (лучше картинкой) "СПАМ". Один раз нажал - и голова не болит.

Понимаю, что это вряд ли впишется в концепцию проекта, теперь уже под SE, но все-таки есть вот такие мысли.